# Colocar div no mesmo lugar com tamanhos de tela diferentes

Tags: html, css

O objetivo é que fique no fundo da `div` em qualquer tamanho da tela

```css
.image {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin-left: -16px;
height: auto;
transition: .5s ease;
backface-visibility: hidden;}

.middle {
transition: .5s ease;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

.container-fluid:hover .middle {
opacity: 1;}
.text {
background-color: #333333;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 662px;
padding: 30px 200px;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="imgs/3.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:101.65%; opacity: 0.8;">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Selecione todo o código fonte depois click no botão `{ }`  para formatá-lo

Comment: Já esta como pediu

Comment: @Maröb no seu projeto há alguma restrição em usar `Bootstrap` ?